# Java Printing Wrong Answer to Arithmetic Equation

Tags: java, math, runtime-error, println

```
System.out.println("3.14 - 5 = " + (3.14 - 5));
```

This statement shows 3.14 - 5 = -1.8599999999999999 in console when the answer is -1.86.

How would I be able to fix this error and what is the reason for the wrong answer being printed in the first place?

Thanks for answering my question, even though it's probably very simple :/.

Comment: Canonical http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.

Comment: You can use `BigDecimal` instead of `int`s and `float`s

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point numbers!

Comment: Seriously? An arithmetic question? Again?

Comment: @Turing85 You must be new here. Dupes are a thing ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton No, but two within 10 minutes is rare, especially when they are that simmilar.

Comment: You can use rounding `System.out.printf("3.14 - 5 = %.2f%n", (3.14 - 5));`

Comment: @Turing85 Actually not so much, especially around finals time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the decimal number is converted to binary it is approximated and not exact.So the subtraction is not exact.

> 3.14 is converted to binary ,so is 5 When the result reconverted to decimal it is not exact.Read about converting decimals to binary from this link :

http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm